# VueJS Вызов дочернего метода из родительского

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Вообщем есть проект на vueJs, я пытаюсь вызвать метод дочернего компонента из родительского, но что-то не выходит.
Вот что в родительском компоненте:

```
<modalWindow :dialog="openFilter" :maxWidth="'720px'">
  <filterComponent ref="filterData" @callUpdateChartAndDataGrid="updateChartAndDataGrid" @callCloseModal="closeModal"></filterComponent>
</modalWindow>

<script>
    import ModalWindow from '@/components/Other/ModalComponent';
    import FilterComponent from '@/components/Other/FilterComponent';

...
onFilter () {
  this.openFilter = !this.openFilter;

  this.$refs.filterData.checkAllBills()
  this.$refs.filterData.checkAllCategories()
  this.$refs.filterData.checkAllCurrencies()
  this.$refs.filterData.checkAllTypes()
},
...
```

Ну методы такие в дочернем точно есть, но ошибка получаю вот такую:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkAllBills')
```

Прошу помощи.

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что this.$refs.filterData === undefined

Comment: @grad Ну это я прочёл, так как сделать, чтобы всё заработало??

Comment: Сделать так, чтобы не было undefined или включить проверку на наличие данных.

Comment: Вот только какое наличие данных, он говорит, что отсутствует сам метод, а не какие-то данные в нём, такое ощущение, что он вообще методы не видит, не понятно, только почему

Comment: Нет, он говорит, что filterData === undefined и что он не может взять метод checkAllBills от undefined

Comment: @grad Но это не отвечает на вопрос как это поправить??

Comment: Отвечает. Выше я писал как это поправить. Если нет данных, то нужно ставить проверку на их наличие и только тогда пользоваться методами. Либо начать дебажить, чтобы понять, почему данные не приходят.

Comment: Без полного кода в sandbox почти невозможно понять вашу причину https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-wind-uyfqgz?file=/src/App.vue Вот рабочий код, такой же как ваш. И если у вас не приходят данные, значит нужно проверять причины(дебажить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем посидел подумал и решил сделать так, поскольку я всё равно буду запускать функции только 1 раз, при первом появлении, я решил сделать так:

```
<modalWindow :dialog="openFilter" :maxWidth="'720px'">
  <FilterComponent :billsParent="bills" :categoriesParent="categories" :currenciesParent="currencies"
    :typesParent="types" @callUpdateChartAndDataGrid="updateChartAndDataGrid" @callCloseModal="closeModal" />
</modalWindow>
...
onFilter () {
  this.openFilter = !this.openFilter;

  if (this.bills.length === 0) {
    this.profile.forEach((item) => {
      this.bills.push(item.id)
    })
  }

  if (this.categories.length === 0) {
    this.category.forEach((item) => {
      this.categories.push(item.id)
    })
  }

  if (this.currencies.length === 0) {
    this.currenciesUser.forEach((item) => {
      this.currencies.push(item.CharCode)
    })
  }

  if (this.types.length === 0) {
    this.arrTypes.forEach((item) => {
      this.types.push(item.id)
    })
  }
},
```

Грубо говоря я объявляю эти же параметры в родительском компоненте при открытии фильтра я их заполняю и передаю в фильтр там в методу mounted я их применяю к параметрам дочернего компонента.